# Using SVN credentials in Hudson to perform custom SVN actions

Tags: svn, hudson

What I'm trying to do here is to perform some sort of SVN action using the credentials that Hudson has stored in it.

E.g.

1. Start a build of project Foo
2. Project Foo starts a shell script
3. Shell script performs a tag of the current source for project Foo using the credentials set in Hudson
4. Build continues

Now I know there are various tagging plugins but these aren't quite what I want since the tagging is dependent on options for the build rather than on the build success. I can script the thing just fine but it all falls down when running under Hudson as svn copy won't work without the required credentials - hence the need to access the one that Hudson has already used to checkout the project.

Comment: Odd. I have a build script that does exactly this, and I don't have to do anything special to run svn commands from the working directory that Hudson checked out. Maybe you're running your copy from the workspace root, instead of the actual working directory?

Comment: @Dave Bacher: does your svn server require authentication?

Comment: @Arthur Ulfeldt: yes, it does (and the svn credentials stored in Hudson have read-write access). It's possible that I did some initial configuration (as the user running the Hudson process) to set up svn so that svn CLI commands would work for the hudson user - e.g. `sudo -u hudson svn info $repo_url` and let svn store the credentials.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://blog.justjohn.us/2010/10/hudson-svn-authentication) article mentions that scripts can access the Hudson SVN credentials from the file system since they are stored in a file in clear text. The article brings up other issues as well, so tread carefully.

Comment: Looks like this is in the right direction - but how do I make use of the subversion.credentials file itself?

Comment: Actually they are not saved in clear text, at least not for me. But I remember long time ago that they weren't encrypted. But I think the fix come in 2008 or 2009. I don't remember anymore.

Comment: The article I've referenced was written in October 2010. Doesn't specify which version of Hudson they are using.

Comment: @Peter, the password may just be base64 encoded. That's what I see. Obscured, but not encrypted.

Comment: @Dave: unfortunately you are right. It is just base64. I would have hoped that something more sophisticated would have been used. But since the source code is available, everyone who really wants to have the password can utilize it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't invent the wheel again. Check out the [Subversion Tagging PLugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Subversion+Tagging+Plugin). According to your description for 3. this plugin should be sufficient for you.

Comment: No, I don't want to tag on successful builds - it's a little more involved. This is for creation of release candidate branches and needs to be a combination of user initiated and on a successful build. Also needs to perform other actions.

Comment: I don't think that you have much luck with reusing Hudson stored credentials.---
But if you use Maven or at least have Maven available, you should be able to use the m2release plugin. http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/M2+Release+Plugin